# how to implement a fake webcam?

Tags: delphi, webcam

I want to play a recorded movie as my webcam? How can i do this , i am a Delphi programmer it's necessary to write a device driver ?

I am waiting for ideas on getting this task done.Thank you!

Comment: I think this is hard. (Just saying...)

Comment: What are you going to do with the webcam?

Comment: Why not use something like VLC player to stream your video? http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html

Comment: There are some applications wich perform this task and i want to create my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [Windows Image Acquisition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368%28VS.85%29.aspx) service. At first glance it looks like you're correct. You will probably have to write a user mode driver to do this. Once this is accomplished you should be able to stream your movie through any software that takes advantage of a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the movie to be accessible to webcam-related APIs and OS features, then yes, you would need to write (or find a thirdp-party) device driver that is usable by multimedia APIs.